# Idea commit failure with hg

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, commit

> 0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: test transaction abort!
>   rollback completed abort: decoding near 'ʷ��ͦ': 'utf8' codec can't
>   decode byte 0xc0 in position 2: invalid start byte!

[image]

Comment: Ok, what's your question? The error message ist pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: I think you tried to commit a bad file, is there a way you could ask Idea to run the command with the `--traceback` option to get more data?

Comment: my question is how to modify the character encoding so that can commit it

Answer (score 0):

Could happen IDEA has passed the file name using wrong encoding. If it works fine from the command line, but fails from the IDEA, it is worth reporting it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: my other colleagues are normal to commit,I think I need to change some places,but I don't know how to modify it

Comment: Check that encoding is configured correctly in the IDE Settings-> Editor-> File Encodings. Try updating mercurial if you use an older version.